# How to make where-filter in “With” (ManyToMany Laravel)?

Tags: laravel-5

Relationship ManyToMany.
I'm trying to make a request:

```
$products=Product::with(['lists' => function($query)
                {
           $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
                }])
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(20);
```

But I get an error.

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `mainlists`.*, `list_products`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `list_products`.`list_id` as `pivot_list_id` from `mainlists` inner join `list_products` on `mainlists`.`id` = `list_products`.`list_id` where `user_id` = 16 and `list_products`.`product_id` in (73, 80, 81, 87, 88, 89)
```

These relationships work correctly in a variety of other queries. 
I think my request is incorrect for the type of relationship ManyToMany.
Because the query is trying to compare multiple products with an pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your `product` and `list` both have `user_id`
you should select which `user_id` you want to consider

like this:

```
$products=Product::with(['lists' => function($query)
            {
       $query->where('list_products.user_id', Auth::id());
            }])
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(20);
```